# CSS - Long text doesn't wrap as expected

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this piece of code using Bootstrap4. What I want to do is have a thumbnail image on and have text on right side of that image. I tried this in

```
          <div class="row">
            <img src="/media/pics/mypic.jpeg" id="image" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail float-left" style="max-width: 100%;" width="150px" height="150px">
                <span class="float-left ml-2 mt-4">
                    <span class="h5 font-weight-bolder text-break d-inline-block">This is a long text. This doesn't wrap well.
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <span class=" h6 text-muted ">
                        New Address, New City
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

When the text is small like 'This is text' the text `<span>`s remain on right side of the image, as desired. But a longer text cause both the `<span>`s to go below the image. I tried `text-wrap` and `text-break` but nothing works.

I want it like this.

Image Image Image
Image Image Image |Long text goes here.|
Image Image Image |It should wrap like this|
Image Image Image |But it doesn't|
Image Image Image

Please help

Comment: you mean on small screen?

Answer (score 1):

you should put the spans together in a flex container:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <img></img>
    <span>text</span>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

also, assign the spans the style `word-break: break-word`

Answer (score 1):

you should add width to the text and insert width and height attr from img to style.
like this

```
 <div class="row">
        <img src="img/chatbg3.jpg" id="image" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail float-left" style="max-width: 100% ;width:150px; height:150px">
            <span style="width: 190px;" class="float-left ml-2 mt-4">
                <span class="h5 font-weight-bolder text-break d-inline-block">This is a long text. This doesn't wrap well.
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class=" h6 text-muted ">
                    New Address, New City
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by using the parts from answers by @Tomer Levitski and @Moti Salamon

I cannot accept both answers. But I really appreciate their answers which helped me.

Here is the answer that worked for me.

```
             <div class="d-flex">
                    <img src="pics/mypic.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail float-left" style="max-width: 100%; width:150px; height:150px;">
                    <span class="float-left ml-2 my-auto">
                        <span class="h5 font-weight-bolder">
                            Long text which will break correctly now
                        </span>
                        <br>
                        <span class=" h6 text-muted ">
                            Some more text here
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

I combined `style="width..; height..;"` and `<div class="d-flex">` from the mentioned answers. also added `my-auto` to the <`span>` so that text is always vertically centered along the image.

Thank you